# "help robot population (to) adapt" -- can I omit "to"?

Tags: to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

Actually I should be working on my bachelor report (it's due tonight), but hey, there are more important things like: Can I omit the **to** in the following sentence?

> ... foster behaviour that would help the robot population (to) adapt to the MONEE environment.

Comment: [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the verb "help," you can use either a to-infinitive or a bare infinitive without affecting the meaning or the grammaticality of the sentence. The bare infinitive version is more common especially in American English.

> "[...]the better practice is to use a bare infinitive after help (if the choice is between a fully expressed infinitive [with *to*] and a bare one [without *to*]) [...]
>
> "The bare infinitive form after *help* overtook the *to*-form in the late 1960s and remains more than twice as common with various verbs."
>
> <sub>Garner (2016), *Garner's Modern English Usage*. Oxford University Press.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/help-somebody-to-do) says:

We use **help** with an object and an infinitive with or without **to**:

- Jack is **helping me to tidy** my CDs. or Jack is **helping me tidy** my CDs.

> Both “**help someone do something**” and “**help someone to do something**” are acceptable. The form without “**to**” seems to be more common in everyday speech than the form with “**to**” *(especially in American English)*, but both forms are common in formal writing.  - [*jakubmarian.com*](https://jakubmarian.com/help-do-vs-help-to-do-vs-help-doing-in-english/)

Judging by the Google Ngram "**help something/somebody adapt**" is far more common than "**help something/somebody to adapt**":

[image: Google Ngram]