# Can the past continuous be used this way?

Tags: tense

1 I missed your call because I was helping fix Jack's car for one hour.

I am not sure if it's correct. It is supposed to mean though, "During that hour I was helping fix Jack's car, I missed your call".

Context. I had been supposed to be helping with the car for 30 minutes but I spent 1 hour and because of that I missed your call.

EDITTED: **helping fixing** substituted for **helping fix**

Comment: *I was helping **[to] fix** Jack's car*. The verb ***to fix*** there has to be the *infinitive* form. It's purely a stylistic choice whether to include the "infinitive marker" ***to*** in this exact context - whether you do or don't makes no difference to the meaning, and personally I don't think either version is any more "formal" or "colloquial" than the other, but opinions may differ on that front.

Comment: Have a look at [Is this “helped + make” combination a form of subjunctive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138295/is-this-helped-make-combination-a-form-of-subjunctive?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is perfectly acceptable, though I would think most native English speakers would say

> because fixing Jack's car took longer than expected,

and only mention the actual time taken if it's specifically brought up.

Incidentally, we would not usually use the word "***one***" like that.  When referring to *one of something* we usually say ***"a/an"***, e.g.

> I was helping fix Jack's car for an hour.

or

> I've not been there in over a year.